# How to groupby and sum if the cell value of certain columns fit specific conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I feel like what I'm trying to do is quite basic but I can't seem to find a similar post here. Please let me know if my post is indeed is duplicate.

The data I have is about transportation crash incidents. The first two columns show the exact number of fatalities and injuries of the incident, but the 3rd and 4th columns (alcohol and cellphone related) only show binary values: 0 (meaning not related) and 1 (meaning related).

The example data is shown as below:

(Sorry the data is not aligned perfectly with the column head, I never knew how to format it correctly. Would appreciate it if anyone can share any tips.)

```
    NAME FATAL# INJURY# ALCOHOL CELL
0   City A  5   1   0   0
1   City B  5   1   0   1
2   City A  3   1   1   0
3   City B  3   1   1   0
4   City A  3   0   1   0
5   City B  2   2   0   0
```

What I want is to do a groupby sum on the first two column, and then calculate the sum of `FATAL` for each city when the `ALCOHOL` or `CELLPHONE` column cell value is 1.

So basically my desired output is:

```
   NAME FATAL# INJURY # ALCOHOL FATALCELL FATAL
0   City A  11  2   6   0
1   City B  10  4   3   5
```

Sorry for the bad formatting, the pictures of the aforementioned dataframes if it helps understanding:

What I have

[image: Have]

What I want

[image: Want]

I know for the first two columns I shall do `df.groupby(['NAME']).['FATAL', 'INJURIES'].sum()`. And as for the second part, I can do `df1.groupby(['NAME','ALCOHOL_RELATED'])['FATAL_COUNT', 'INJURY_COUNT'].sum()` but then I would lose the total count columns.

How shall I accomplish this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is clearest to join additional series to your dataframe, *then* `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['CityA', 'CityB', 'CityA', 'CityB', 'CityA', 'CityB'],
                   'FATAL#': [5, 5, 3, 3, 3, 2],
                   'INJURY#': [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
                   'ALCOHOL': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                   'CELL': [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]})

# construct fatals dataframe and join
fatals = df.iloc[:, -2:].mul(df['FATAL#'], axis=0).add_prefix('FATAL_')
df = df.join(fatals)

# define columns to sum and groupby
sum_cols = ['FATAL#', 'INJURY#'] + df.columns[-2:].tolist()
res = df.groupby('NAME')[sum_cols].sum().reset_index()

print(res)

    NAME  FATAL#  INJURY#  FATAL_ALCOHOL  FATAL_CELL
0  CityA      11        2              6           0
1  CityB      10        4              3           5
```

Comment: Wow, amazing answer. Thanks for the fast and detailed reply. I didn't even know about `mul` and `add_prefix` functions. Just one thing that I don't understand: what does `axis = 0` do? The documentation didn't give any example, and it shows `axis = 'columns'`, but I don't have a column with name `0`. Could you please just elaborate a little more on this? Thanks again.

Comment: [`mul` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html) do mention `axis`, here `axis=0` is the same as `axis='index'` and means multiply row-wise.

Comment: Thanks. I got it when I was playing around with your code. But due to the limit of my knowledge/imagination, I can't seem to figure out how `axis = 'columns'` would work. When we put these two df side by side, how else can we multiply it other than by rows?

Comment: @BowenLiu, I don't think it does. Which his why we use `axis='index'` !

Answer (score 0):

In a single groupby:

```
df.groupby('NAME').agg(
lambda grp: [grp.loc[grp[col] > 0, 'FATAL#'].sum() if col != 'INJURY#' else grp[col].sum() 
             for col in grp if col != 'FATAL#'])


>>>df

NAME    FATAL#  INJURY# ALCOHOL CELL
A   11  2   6   0
B   10  4   3   5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` to create `ALCOHOL_FATAL` and `CELL_FATAL` columns.

```
import numpy as np

df['ALCOHOL_FATAL'] = np.where(df['ALCOHOL'] == 1, df['FATAL'], 0)
df['CELL_FATAL'] = np.where(df['CELL'] == 1, df['FATAL'], 0)
```

After, drop the columns `ALCOHOL` and `CELL` and groupby the data

```
df.drop(['ALCOHOL', 'CELL'], axis = 1, inplace=True)
df.groupby('NAME', as_index=False).sum()

    NAME    FATAL # INJURY #    ALCOHOL_FATAL   CELL_FATAL
0   CityA   11  2   6   0
1   CityB   10  4   3   5
```